# CiviVolunteer error after upgrade to Civi 5.11.0 on joomla

Tags: joomla, civireport, civivolunteer

Running civicrm 5.11.0 with CiviVolunteer on joomla 3.9.5 PHP 7.1 (as well a second site with the same problem on PHP 7.0)
I am running API v4 version 4.3.0
CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1

Since upgrading from civi 5.10.0 to 5.11.0 I receive the following error when running the Volunteer Report.

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error
Return to home page.

From the error_log file:
[28-Apr-2019 22:08:34 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home/[my account]/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php on line 151

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning you describe is fixed in the version of CiviVolunteer on github but they haven't tagged a release. The error sounds slightly different & turning on debugging might get more info.

However I logged an issue asking them to tag a release since there are unreleased civivolunteer fixes https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/issues/508

You can get the latest civivolunteer code from github in the meantime - https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/archive/master.zip and see if that helps